# Android Button Onclick

Tags: java, android

I'm having problems with on click method. I want my button, when it's clicked on the phone to switch the layout view from main.xml to xx.xml

```
package my.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ExperiencerlActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activ`enter code here`ity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my button code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:onClick="setLogin"
    android:text="Login" />
```

Comment: Do not mix the click events!

Answer (score 110):

> If you write like this in Button tag in xml file :   **android:onClick="setLogin"** then

Do like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn"
    android:onClick="onClickBtn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in Code part:

```
public class StartUpActivity extends Activity 
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);    
    }

    public void onClickBtn(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked on Button", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}
```

and no need all this:

```
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
 });
```

Check it once;

Answer (score 15):

You need to make the same method name **both** in layout XML and java code.

If you use `android:onClick="setLogin"` then you need to make a method with the same name, **setLogin**:

```
// Please be noted that you need to add the "View v" parameter
public void setLogin(View v) {

}
```

**ADVICE:**
Do not mix layout with code by using `android:onClick` tag in your XML. Instead, move the click method to your class with `OnClickListener` method like:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 });
```

Make a layout just for layout and no more. It will save your precious time when you need to refactoring for [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 7):

**Method 1:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
         startActivty(i);
        }
```

**Method 2:**

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this :

```
   public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           startActivity(new Intent("com.droidnova.android.splashscreen.MyApp"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions for this are :-

**(1)** do not put onClick in xml

**(2)** remove

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

and put

```
public void setLogin(View v) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Note that you cannot use both solutions together!

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code of how to add a button named Add.
You should declare the variable as a member variable, and the naming convention for member variables is to start with the letter "m".

Hit Alt+Enter on the classes to add the missing references.

Add this to your activity_main.xml:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ADD"
     />
```

Add this to your MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button mButtonAdd; 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mButtonAdd = findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);

        mButtonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what code you are trying to execute when the button is pressed. You've got the onClick property set in your xml file to a method called setLogin. For clarity, I'd delete this line `android:onClick="setLogin"` and call the method directly from inside your `onClick()` method.

Also you can't just set the display to a new XML, you need to start a new activity with an Intent, a method something like this would be appropriate

```
 private void setLogin() {

 Intent i = new Intent(currentActivity.this, newActivity.class);
 startActivty(i);

 }
```

Then set the new Activity to have the new layout.

Answer (score 0):

this will sort it for you

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button but1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent int1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,xxactivity.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }
    });
}
```

You just need to amend the xxactivity to the name of your second activity

Answer (score 0):

Use **Layout inflater** method in your button click. it will change your current .xml to targeted .xml file. 
Google for layout inflater code.