# How to open specific Fragment from other activity onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 fragment in viewpager (Easy, Normal, Hard, Advance) and I just want to open Normal fragment when onClick from other activity.

## PageAdapter:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
}
```

## FragmentActivity:

```
public class level_selection extends FragmentActivity {

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.level_selection);
    //initialsie the pager
    this.initialisePaging();
}

private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Easy.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Normal.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Hard.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Advance.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new PagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
}
}
```

Based on code above anybody can guide me on how to modify it to allow open fragment "Normal" by onClick from other Activity?

Best Regards,

Comment: set pager.setCurrentItem(1) after pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter); or add Normal as first item to fragments list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make `pager` a class field and then use from `onClick` method:

```
 pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

This assumes your "normal" `Fragment` always has the index 1 in your `List` (from you code, it is actually at index 1)

Comment: can you explain please how the whole OnClick process done ??

Comment: @ReemAziz take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231309/android-button-onclick) question to get an idea about how "the whole OnClick process" works

Comment: No you don't understand my Question I mint the onClick of the activity and what should i pass to  the intent to to get the position  of the ViewPager .. I really did what you said , but still give me wrong  position since I combine  BottomNavigationView with ViewPager

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
pager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

**OR**

```
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Normal.class.getName()));    
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Easy.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Hard.class.getName()));
fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Advance.class.getName()));
```