# onClick view is already defined

Tags: java, android

I am trying to work with two buttons on one screen and I want to have two different actions occur when each button is clicked. This is my code and I am getting the error message onClick view is already defined on the method titles of both onClick methods. Any help is greatly appreciated.
     import android.content.Intent;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Button button3;
private Button button2;
private EditText editText;
private EditText editText9;
private EditText editText10;
private EditText editText11;
private EditText editText12;
private EditText editText13;
private EditText editText14;
private TextView textView;
private TextView textView22;
private View view;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2_main);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText9);
    editText10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
    editText11 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText11);
    editText12 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText12);
    editText13 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText13);
    editText14 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText14);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textView22 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView22);


}
public void onClick (View view) {
    this.view = view;
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button3) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity.class);
        MainActivity2.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}


public void onClick (View view){
    if (view.getId() == R.id.button2) {
        String value8 = editText.getText().toString();
        String value9 = editText9.getText().toString();
        String value10 = editText10.getText().toString();
        String value11 = editText11.getText().toString();
        String value12 = editText12.getText().toString();
        String value13 = editText13.getText().toString();
        String value14 = editText14.getText().toString();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: potential duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231309/android-button-onclick)

Comment: @mike start studying java dude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two onClick methods with the same parameters so it doesn't know which to use. Combine the two and it should work.